# How to prevent all audio and video media from starting in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, audio, video

I am really sick and tired of needing to keep my PC muted because I navigate to a webpage and get spammed with auto playing audio or video.

Steps I have already done:

- Removed flash
- Java is not installed
- configured media.autoplay.enabled to false

I have read this post https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/776893 that offers no solutions. The top suggestion is a Firefox addon that has since been removed. NoScript isn't a viable option, i don't want to break the entire internet by disabling javascript. Also I'm not even sure if javascript is needed for these videos in the first place with HTML5.

Must also include ways to disable audio, not only video playback. Audio is substantially worse than video.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound I demand that all video & audio only play with my explicit content (ie **i click play**). For some reason this seems to be impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop automatic video play in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/370246/stop-automatic-video-play-in-firefox)

Comment: @Toto this question does not duplicate that link, that's only about video, not about audio.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question still pop-up in search, it may be useful to post the actual solution:
[Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1371593/204988)