# Disable Video Buffering in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, html5

I use cellular networks for browsing. I use Firefox as my primary browser. I need to know how to stop buffering of HTML5 Videos. I have already stopped Flash Videos so as to speed up the time taken to load a page. For disabling auto load of HTML5 Videos I have already done the steps outlined in this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/370246/stop-automatic-video-play-in-firefox). But I need a mechanism to stop the buffering of HTML5 Videos till I click or want to. I other words no HTML5 Videos should be buffered in Firefox.

Can somebody please help me how to do this?

Comment: @JasonStack - If you have a question you should ask it.  Your comment question is unlikely to be answered in a meaningful way.

Comment: Ok sure, I removed the question on question comment!

Comment: @JasonStack In Firefox one can disable flash by going to menu button and selecting Add-ons. Scroll down till you come to "Shockwave Flash". Change the option to "Ask to activate". This will disable flash entirely on all of the websites that you visit.You will have to click to enable flash. Since Flash is disabled entirely it will not buffer too. The only problem with this approach is that this is either all or nothing approach. One cannot selectively whitelist some sites and black list the rest.

Comment: @Amardeep thanks. This will be very useful for me as I, too, use cellular network.

Comment: I don't think that you might be able to disable HTML5 video buffering because Firefox does not seem to be using an add-on for this purpose so that it could be disabled.

Comment: @JasonStack I hope somebody will be able to point me in the right direction. I was hoping to be able to do this without an extension or an addon if possible.

Comment: @Amardeep, I tried to disable HTML5 buffering by going to about:preferences->applications, and then trying to change Action for all media content types to `Always Ask' hoping it will ask which application to use (e.g. VLC) for buffering media. However, it didn't seem to affect HTML5 buffering behavior.

Comment: @JasonStack my suggestion was for Flash only. It was not applicable to HTML5 Videos which are rendered using the video tag of HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent auto-pay:

Type "about:config" in the address bar, hit Enter, and click through the confirmation screen. Search for a setting called "media.autoplay.enabled," then double-click to disable it.

Prevent buffering:

Set media.cache_readahead_limit to 0.

Set media.cache_resume_threshold to 10 and media.cache_readahead_limit to 30.

Now you won't auto-play, if you choose to play a video you won't buffer much; if you play faster than you downloaded (empty your buffer due to high resolution, or low compression due to complex motion) you'll get the spinner, so increase the values to avoid that.

If you never want to watch videos over cellular data connections you can choose in the settings to use Wi-Fi only, but that didn't seem to be what you were asking.