# Disable autoplay in Firefox 66

Tags: firefox

A couple of months back (I think it was with v63), Firefox changed the way to disable autoplay from setting

```
media.autoplay.enabled = false
```

to setting

```
media.autoplay.default = 1    # or 2 for ask
```

and possibly

```
media.autoplay.allow-muted = false
```

This is all fine and good. But as of v66, this doesn't seem to work anymore, either - playback starts as soon as a page with a video in it gets loaded*. This occurs in a fresh profile with nothing changed but these settings.

Autoplay is still prevented when entering a url by hand/ reloading a page. The only cases that fail are clicking a link or being redirected (after a login, for example).

So my question is this: **What is the current way to disable autoplay everywhere in Firefox v66?**

*actually, only if it gets loaded in the foreground - background tabs don't start playback even upon receiving focus. Which isn't really the expected outcome from setting `media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground = true` (the default value) if autoplay were either allowed or disabled completely, either.

Edit: The precise version installed is `66.0+linuxmint1+tessa`, on the off chance that it makes a difference.

Comment: I have `media.autoplay.default` set to 1 and it works on youtube. Have you tried with a [fresh profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)?

Comment: @tastytea I have now. No luck though :/

Comment: Is autoplay prevented when you reload the page or when you enter the URL manually?

Comment: Yes. The only time something actually gets played if I click a link or get redirected (ie. after logging in somewhere).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop automatic video play in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/370246/stop-automatic-video-play-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox allows autoplaying if you visited the URL by clicking on a link on the same site. For example, if you are on Youtube and click on a Youtube link, autoplay will not be prevented. To disable autoplay in these cases, set

```
media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed = false
```

in about:config.

[According to ghacks.net](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/21/firefox-improved-autoplay-blocking/), this setting was originally introduced to stop videos from auto-playing on websites you didn't interact with. The effect that it overrides media.autoplay.default = 1 seems to be a bug.

Comment: Do you have a reference link for this? If so, please [edit] and add to your answer.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. But I don't understand why this used to work in v63-65 - that setting is not new 0o

Comment: @DavidPostill I found this out by trying. I found no source with an explanation.

Comment: They [recommend the same](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/b35aed/is_mediaautoplaydefault_no_longer_supported_after/). *media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed* to false, also *media.autoplay.allow-muted* to false, keeping *media.autoplay.default* to 1, and unchecking the box in about:preferences#privacy to automatically play sounds.